# load balancing wcf service with basichttp binding

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I am having a wcf service which is hosted on iis, when 10 to 15 users accessing the service at a time, it is ends with an exception stating httprequesttimedoutwithoutdetails. I have increased the send, receive, open, closed timeout configuration but still in getting the issue. Can anyone please suggest any idea.

Comment: What does your service does? 15 users aren't that many, perhaps you're beating hard your db, or you've got a lock on it.

Comment: Yes, we are calling lengthy stored procedure. Will nolock avoid this lock problem.

Comment: nolock on the statements of the sp ? Oh, no, definitely I can't suggests this. nolock is something to be used extremely carefully or better avoid at all.

If your sp can't be optimized to run in just a few seconds I recommend you to go async: write the task to do somewhere and return immediately. Then let some other thread/process do the work for you.

You could have a look to http://hangfire.io/ to run your stored procedure in background and the somehow notify your user that it has completed

Comment: Thank u for your reply